# How to insert a big (28 x 28) matrix in latex?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I'm trying to fit a 28 $\times$ 28 matrix in the page but it's not setting in page. The rows are taking two lines to come. Is there any way to put a matrix like this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE community. It seem that you have a problem like *how to put elephant into lady suitcase* ... To help you somehow, wee need to see small complete document  called MWE (Minimal Working Example)  with your matrix, which we can compile as it is.

Comment: Even if it's a matrix, you can find useful hints in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options